# Adding constant character to Python list

Tags: python

I have a Python list like

```
Period = [328, 329, 330]
```

I want to add a letter 'P' before each and every item in the list.

Example output should look like `[P328, P329, P330]`

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Your desired list contains values that are not legal Python values.  Did you perhaps want strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a list comprehension:

```
Period = [328, 329, 330]
period = ['P'+str(x) for x in Period]
print(period)
>>> ['P328', 'P329', 'P330']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what's called "list comprehension" in Python to create a new list with the prefixed items:

```
prefixed_periods = ['P' + str(item) for item in Period]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add strings and integers directly. With Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings with a list comprehension:

```
res = [f'P{num}' for num in Period]
```